# URL of advertisement being fetched by Adview

Tags: android, adview

I want to capture the image shown by Adview i.e., the actual advertisement. I do not want to take a screenshot. Only the actual image itself. If that is not possible, is there a way to capture the URL to the image so that I can fetch it separately?

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably against the terms of service of your ad network, so you shouldn't do it. Not unless they expose a public API for it, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I do understand that it may be against terms of service. However, this is part of some of my PhD research and the code for this is not to be deployed anywhere except the phone being used for this research.

Comment: Well, it would be highly dependent on the actual library. Your best bet would probably be to write the whole AdView as an image on disk. Also keep in mind that not all ads are images -- some are text or HTML. As for the actual download URLs, some libraries write them to logcat, so you could capture this periodically and scrape it.

Comment: Hi Nikaolay, Thanks for the suggestions. I am not sure I know how to do the first thing --- Adview as an image on disk. But I talked to a lab colleague and I think I can try to scrape/parse the logcat output because the logcat does print the URL used to fetch the image.

Comment: There are many answers about this on SO, but something like adView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/image.jpg"));` should do it. If you get an event when a new ad is received you can use it trigger the save.

Comment: Hi again. I followed up on both techniques. No success. For getting the adview as image, the bitmap when calling getDrawingCache() is 'null'. Others' suggestions on rectifying this error has borne no fruit. Scraping and parsing logcat was unsuccessful as well since the 'exact' URL used to fetch the image is not being logged. Since setting a proxy has had no effect, I am left with no recourse except to either a) root the phone and sniff the traffic or b) perform a network sniffing on a private network with a linux/wireshark box as the gateway. Thanks for the suggestions. They were instructive.

Comment: There are other, slightly more complex ways of capturing a view as an image. Do a quick search and you should find a few ways to do it.